# How can I move a database from OnPremise to Azure using SSMS?

Tags: azure

I have a large database, about 6Gig in size , its a .bacpac file and I want to copy it to Azure. I am using SSMS and selecting "Import Data-tier Application".
It takes a very long time and i get an error "System out of memory exception"

How can I transfer the database to Azure ?

Comment: check if this can be helpful.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-import?view=azuresql&tabs=azure-powershell

you can try creating .bak extension of backup export use SSMS to restore which is quick

Comment: How can i get a .bak file ? I just connect to the Azure Sql Server -> right click on the database and select Tasks->Export Dat-Tier Application and it saves as .bacpac not .bak

Comment: So cant i just open the database and use the Copy option (being that the copy is in the same subscription ? Just enter the Destination database in Azure Portal ?

Comment: If i use Azure Copy , the source db is a Live db , will the their possibly be any issues like locks when the Copy is in progress ? This might be a better option for  5G db .

Comment: .bak file extension -> https://support.solarwinds.com/SuccessCenter/s/article/Back-up-and-restore-SQL-database-instance-using-a-BAK-file?language=en_US

if sourcedb is livedb, migration recommended to go to SQL Managed Instance.
If ready to use PaaS (Azure SQL Database), then either Migration Assistant or Backup/Restore by uploading db file to storage account and import or SSMS.

Comment: Are you copying fron on prem to azure or azure to azure ? it s not cleared when I read you comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [Microsoft® Data Migration Assistant](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53595).
Here's a tutorial: [Tutorial: Migrate SQL Server to Azure SQL Database using DMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dms/tutorial-sql-server-to-azure-sql)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/31834113)